# How to sync database schema with Entity Framework in model-first without migrations

Tags: sql, entity-framework, edmx

I have made changes to my model-first EDMX file, and now I want to apply the changes to my database. I've just added a new table and some new fields, nothing destructive. I want to apply the "diff" to my database, but without all the hassle of database migrations. What I actually need is a *non-destructive* SQL file containing only the differences.

Currently, I am doing this manually by creating new database SQL from model, deleting all the code non-relevant to the table I am creating, and running the SQL. However, my table is currently empty so I can do this destructively. Moreover, if there are any changes referencing other entities too (e.g. adding a new foreign key to one of the existing tables), the SQL is, obviously, destructive. So I need to add them manually by writing my own SQL.

Is there any tool or a shorter workaround that would automate this whole process? I am looking for something that will compare the current database and the newly created EDMX, and apply only the diff into the database, as a one time process. The whole database migration system of Entity Framework is an extreme overhead and unnecessary work, the whole process, which will run only once, can be boiled down to a single SQL file. Is there such a tool/method? What is the best practice for this (other than EF migrations)?

Comment: I'm not aware of any up-to-date tool doing this (some outdated only). Maybe you should switch to database-first.

Comment: @GertArnold I could, but then I'm losing the whole point of using the EDMX designer..

Comment: I've been rutinely checking to see if something like this has become available for the past year but nothing yet. It seems to me like a massive oversight on the part of the EF team.

Comment: @VladTamas it's sad to see there is no such tool. Everyone eventually do some changes eventually, and we're forced to do unnecessarry and complicated work for such a basic thing. Sad.